# How to get and list all the installed/available navigations apps along with their icons in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

As the subject states, I'm looking for a way to get and list all the available navigations apps installed in the Android device along with their respective icons. Let's say the devices has Google Maps and Waze, I want to get all the info of these apps like their name, icon and package in order to open them from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
val packageManager: PackageManager = viewLayer.activity.packageManager
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0"))
val resolvedInfoList: List<ResolveInfo> = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(
    intent,
    PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY
)
for (resolvedInfo in resolvedInfoList) {
    val packageName: String = resolvedInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName
    val appName: String = resolvedInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString()
    val launcherIcon: Drawable = resolvedInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
}
```